Understanding statistical significance
I have 16 birds (191978,191984, 191977, 191980, 191986, 201446, 191983, 201447, 211598, 211590, 211595, 191981, 211591, 201441, 201445, 211592). There are 6 males and 10 females. The dataset is called 'Gbirds_sex' I have the number of times they revisit their release site (visitIdx). I also have (timeInside) column to show the residence time within the release site. I want to do statistical analysis in R to see if sex affects number of revisits (visitIdx) and residence time (timeInside).
I am confused as to which test works best and the R code for it. LLM, GLM. Should I use a random intercept.
enter image description here
I have tried these:
    #1
    #visitIdx is a count variable so
    # Fit a GLMM with Poisson distribution
    library(lme4)
    model_glmm <- glmer(visitIdx ~ sex + (1 | id), family =
    poisson(), data = Gbirds_sex)
    summary(model_glmm)
    #2
    #residenceTime is continuous, we'll use the Gaussian family.
    # Fit the GLMM with Gaussian response distribution and random      
    intercept for each individual
    model_timeInside_Gaussian <- lm(timeInside ~ sex, data =       
    Gbirds_sex)
    summary(model_timeInside_Gaussian)

However, dispersion was high (2.8)
Should I now use:
library(glmmTMB)
model_glmm_nb <- glmmTMB(visitIdx ~ sex + (1 | id), family = nbinom2(), data = Gbirds_sex)
summary(model_glmm_nb)

Any help would be fantastic!

Would be helpfull if you also share the output of your code. Since we do no have the dataset, we cannot reproduce.

Would be helpfull if you also share the output of your code. Since we do no have the dataset, we cannot reproduce.

Have you multiple data points per id? If not, I don't see a reason to use a mixed model, else, your glmmTMB model looks good. You should check your distributional assumptions, e.g. using performance::check_model() to see if you really need the nbinom2() family, or if you model the dispersion parameter directly in glmmTMB (using the dispformula argument).
